# Matlab Plot Function For Complex Numbers

Tags: matlab

I Have This Function:

```
z = 1 + 2i;
```

z^n = 1;
plat(z);

I Want To Draw Its Chart.
Please Help Me.

Comment: Wha is "plat"? Do you mean `plot`? Anyway, your question is very unclear

Comment: Yes. I Have This Complex Number. z = 1+2i. I Want To Plot This (z^n = 1). Thanks

Comment: Do you want to plot the _solutions_ of _z^n = 1_?

Comment: Yesss ! That It. Can You Help Me?!

Comment: The solutions to _z^n=1_ are `exp(-(pi*1i*2*k)/n)` for `k`=0,...,n-1. So: `n=10; plot(exp(-(pi*1i*2*(0:n-1))/n), 'o'); axis square` (choose `n` as needed)

Comment: I've written my comment as an answer so that you can accept it and thus remove the question from the unanswered list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **solutions to the equation *z*<sup>*n*</sup> = 1** are `exp(-(pi*1i*2*k)/n)` for `k`=`0`,...,`n-1`. So:

```
n = 10; %// choose n as needed
plot(exp(-(pi*1i*2*(0:n-1))/n), 'o');
axis square
```